# sublime-text color picker tool does not work in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, sublime-text

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS version, then installed sublime-text 3 (build 3103) and ColorPicker tool.

I can access the ColorPicker tool using Ctrl+Shift+C and select a color, but the selected color does not appear on the window. ie. after I select a particular color and click <kbd>ok</kbd> nothing happens except closing the window. The color hashcode does not appear nor replace existing color value. It was working fine in my previous 14.04 version.

Where should I look for the problems???

Answer (score 3):

Edit `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/ColorPicker/lib/linux_colorpicker.py`

Search this line:

```python
if color_sel.run() == getattr(Gtk, 'RESPONSE_OK', Gtk.ResponseType.OK):
```

Change it to:

```python
if color_sel.run() == getattr(Gtk, 'RESPONSE_OK', Gtk.ResponseType):
```

and save.

Source: https://github.com/weslly/ColorPicker/issues/82

Answer (score 2):

Verify the shebang script-file-path is pointing to the correct python.
In my case I was using python3 but the script was pointing to python2

So I edited the file,

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/ColorPicker/lib/linux_colorpicker.py
```

in which the first line was

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to call python3 like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

it helped me.

I hope it will help someone who may happen to face the same issue in future :)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the some dependencies worked for me:

```
sudo apt install python-gi, python-pkg-resources, python-cairo, python-gi-cairo
```

I tried installing another color picker (called `picker`) from a `.deb` file and after installation it refused to work without the above dependencies. Once installed the color picker in Sublime also began working again.

Answer (score 0):

First open the sublime text editor and go to the Preferences>>Browse Packages.
Now go to the ColorPicker>>lib and run the `linux_colorpicker.py` file using

```
$ python linux_colorpicker.py
```

If it is showing error like

```
import gtk as Gtk not found
```

then install the python gtk and glib using commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

now run the same python file and it will start working.

Comment: Hi Amrit and welcome to askubuntu!  Please format your future commands in your post by using 4 spaces, or select with mouse and type ctrl+k .